# how to get data in ajax.done()?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I get nickname, `attack_point` data using ajax

```
var nickname;
$.ajax({
            method:'GET',
            url:get_gamestart_api_url,

        }).done(function(data){

            $get_id.append("<li class='nickname'>" character.nickname+"</li>",
                "<li class='attack_point'>" character.status.attack_point+"</li>",
                    );
            nickname=character.nickname;
        });

console.log(nickname);
```

The script shows me `undefined`.

I think `console.log(nickname);` was executed before `done()`.  Why is this happening?

plase somebody help me thank you :)

Comment: Make sure you read the entire accepted answer of the suggested duplicate, and **understand** it. If you're going to be using JS, it's **imperative** that you know how to handle async code, and how it differs from synchronous code.

Comment: @Andreas, and  'Carcigenicate' thanks for the good advise! from now on, I can understand different between Asynchronous, synchronous! my question is so stupid,, I tried eat bread before get it... thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `console.log(nickname);` was executed before `.done()` because Ajax request are asynchronous, which means they are procesed in the background. That means that the program isn't necesarily executed in the order you wrote it.
If you want `console.log(nickname);` to be executed once the Ajax request is done, you should include it in the `.done()` function

Comment: thank you @Larpee but this advise not a solution for me, becuase I want use nickname value outside

Comment: @Min What exactly do you want to do? Maybe I can help you with that

Comment: Thank you @Larpee, here is my [link](https://gist.github.com/deadlylaid/5cc840a9ceccfbadead5f2c835591153)  what i want, but I solved my problem already using `callback()` but Thank you for your kindness. Larpee

Comment: @Min Okay, I'm glad you solved your problem